# cmake source_group não tem efeito

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake

Estou tentando organizar o projeto gerado no visual studio, pra isso estou utilizando a função `source_group` para adicionar os diretórios que eu quero, só que não parece surtir efeito:

```
set(CPP_FILES_REGEX "\\b(\\w|\\d)+\\b\\.(hpp|cpp|c|h)")

source_group("my_folder" REGULAR_EXPRESSION     "${sourcers_dir}\/${CPP_FILES_REGEX}")

add_executable(my_executable ${sourcers_dir}/main.cpp ${sourcers_dir}/teste.hpp)
```

Eu testei a expressão regular aqui: [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) e funciona, o projeto gerado continua com os folders padrão: Header e Sources.